# How do I make my own online storage server?

Tags: windows, backup, storage

I have an external hard drive and I want to make it accessible on the web for a few friends so they can backup more easily.

I use Windows 7 Pro. What would be the best, simplest and most secure method to do this?
What software should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/) it supports peer-to-peer backups.
You can set it up so you backup data to your friend's computer and vise-versa. 
You can also backup to a local network share or an external HD

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just installed CrashPlan and it's not quite what I'm looking for. Isn't there an Windows option, to share on the web and use a user and pass; something like Windows Remote Desktop but on online?

Comment: the idea is that you add your friend as a backup destination. you have an "Invite" link in your backup destination tab. (your friend needs to install this software too...)

Comment: look at this video tour http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6qSJIkcWss

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your machine as an FTP server .
You can use [Serv-U](http://www.serv-u.com/) for this purpose.
Just ensure you can access your server from outside
If you have a static Ip it should not be difficult , but if you have a dynamic ip head over to [DynaDNS](http://www.dynadns.org/) to help you out

Comment: you can check this tutorial in this regard http://lifehacker.com/#!130806/how-to-set-up-a-home-ftp-server

Answer (score 2):

Another option it consider is the [Pogoplug](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0033WSDR4).  This device lets you share any USB device.  You connect the Ethernet and the USB device to the Pogoplug and then use the included software to setup sharing and you good to go.  Very easy.

Advantages:

- You don't have to leave your computer running all the time to have the device available.
- Simple and easy to set up.
- Full control over who can access the files on the USB device.
- You can access the device via HTTP